# Use PowerShell to divide two decimals

Tags: powershell

This seems easy, but after searching, I have come up empty-handed.

How can I divide two decimals in powershell?

```
204.50 / 1,917.75
```

Throws the following error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Division'.
At line:1 char:1
+ 204.50 / 1,917.75
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Division:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Comment: Step one: don't use commas for thousand separators.

Comment: I was typing my answer as these two comments came in.

Comment: Ugh. Fail. I guess I need more coffee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try leaving the comma out.  What you've typed looks like 204.50 divided by 1 and then 917.75

Comment: In other words: equivalent to `$a / $b,$c`

Answer (score 0):

[Walter Mitty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33570543/45375) is an effective solution.

To **explain *why*** `204.50 / 1,917.75` failed:

**PowerShell number literals** (a) **always use `.` as the decimal mark**, irrespective of the current culture, and (b) **do *not* support use of a thousands separator** (such as `,`).

This implies that `1,917.75` is *not recognized as a number literal*, which  begs the question ([kinda](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=beg%20the%20question)): *how is it parsed*?

`,` is the *array-construction* operator in PowerShell: that is, tokens separated by `,` constitute the *elements of an array*.

Thus, `1,917.75`, is the equivalent of `@( 1, 917.75 )`: a *2-element array* containing `[int]` `1` and `[double]` `917.75`.

**`,` has higher precedence than `/`**, the division operator, so that `204.50 / 1,917.75` is the equivalent of:

```
 204.50 / @( 1, 917.75 )
```

That is, PowerShell *tries* to divide `[double]` literal `204.50` by *array* `@( 1, 917.75 )`

Since PowerShell doesn't know how to divide *anything* by an *array* (generically represented in PowerShell as `[System.Object[]]`), you get the following error message:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Division'.
```

That is, PowerShell looks for a way to apply division operator `/` (`op_Division`) to *array* operands, and since that isn't defined, an error occurs.

---

As an aside: **PowerShell *does* overload *some* operators to work with arrays, but only if the array is on the *LHS*** (the left-hand side operand).

Operators `-eq` / `ne`, `-like` / `-notlike`, `-match` / `-notmatch` (do let me know if I'm missing any) accept an *array* as the LHS and a *scalar* as the RHS, in which case the operator acts as a *filter*:

The operator is applied *individually* to the *elements* of the LHS (against the scalar on the RHS), and the subset of elements for which the operation returns `$true` is returned as a *subarray* of the input array; e.g.:

```
@( 'donald trump', 'hillary clinton', 'gary johnson' ) -notmatch 'trump'
```

outputs `@( 'hillary clinton', 'gary johnson' )`, the subarray of the input containing only those elements that do not contain the substring `trump`.